# How to create a Stripe recurring contribution if subscription was not created in Civi

Tags: recurring-contributions, stripe

Earlier this year, our Stripe webhook was wrong for a period of time when the extension version changed to 5.2 but the webhook did not meet the new URL format.

During this period, recurring contributions that were sent to Stripe were successfully posted there but not in Civi. They continue to show in Stripe and not Civi.

If I look under one of these records that had this issue underneath their contributions tab > recurring contributions it is blank. That would be the problem I assume...so could we manually insert the right data into the civicrm_contribution_recur table and make subsequent contributions talk back to Civi?

I see in Stripe that it tries to send the IPN 7 times and fails.

Note, everything works for anyone who signs up now, just an issue with failed subscriptions in Civi.